# swift/scenekit problems getting touch events from SCNScene and overlaySKScene

Tags: swift, scenekit

Good afternoon, I'm trying to figure out how to get touch notifications from an SCNNode & a SKSpriteNode from an SCNScene overlayed with a SKScene.

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
var scnView:SCNView!
var scnScene:SCNScene!
var sprite: spritekitHUD!
var cameraNode: SCNNode!
var shape: SCNNode!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupScene()
     }

func setupScene() {
    scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    scnView.delegate = self
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
    scnScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/scene.scn")
    scnView.scene = scnScene
    sprite=spritekitHUD(size: self.view.bounds.size, game: self)
    scnView.overlaySKScene=sprite
    cameraNode = scnScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "camera",
                                              recursively: true)!
    shape=scnScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "shape", recursively: true)
    shape.name="ThreeDShape"
    }

 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
 let touch = touches.first!
 let location = touch.location(in: scnView)
 let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(location, options: nil)
 if let result = hitResults.first {
      handleTouchFor(node: result.node)
     }
  }

func handleTouchFor(node: SCNNode) {
  if node.name == "ThreeDShape" {
         print("SCNNode Touched")
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Spritekit overlay scene

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class spritekitHUD: SKScene{

var game:GameViewController!
var shapeNode: SKSpriteNode!

init(size: CGSize, game: GameViewController){
    super.init(size: size)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    let spriteSize = size.width/12
    self.shapeNode= SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shapeNode")
    self.shapeNode.size = CGSize(width: spriteSize, height: spriteSize)
    self.shapeNode.position = CGPoint(x: spriteSize + 8, y: spriteSize + 8)
    self.shapeNode.name="test"
    self.game=game


    self.addChild(self.pauseNode)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch=touches.first else{
        return
    }
    let location=touch.location(in: self)
    if self.atPoint(location).name=="test" {
     print("Spritekit node pressed")
    }
 }
}
```

so with this I can successfully get notifications that my spritenode has been touched on my overlaySKScene but I cant figure out how to get a notification that my SCNode has been touched. If you cant have 2 touchesbegan functions does anyone have any ideas how I can handle the 3d events with 2d events at the same time?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is "lifted" straight out of Xcode's Game template......

Add a gesture recognizer in your viewDidLoad:

```
       // add a tap gesture recognizer
       let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  
           #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    func handleTap(_ gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    // retrieve the SCNView
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

    // check what nodes are tapped
    let p = gestureRecognize.location(in: scnView)
    let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: [:])
    // check that we clicked on at least one object
    if hitResults.count > 0 {
        // retrieved the first clicked object
        let result: AnyObject = hitResults[0]

        // result.node is the node that the user tapped on
        // perform any actions you want on it


    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use an `SKScene` overlay of an `SCNView` for user controls, (eg you want to implement a button in the SKScene overlay that "consumes" the touch), but also have touches that don't hit the controls to pass through and register in the underlying `SCNView`, you have to do this: set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false` on the SKScene overlay itself, but then to `true` on any individual elements within that overlay that you'd like to act as buttons.

```
let overlay = SKScene(fileNamed: "overlay")
overlay?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
let pauseButton = overlay?.childNode(withName: "pauseButton") as? Button 
// Button is a subclass of SKSpriteNode that overrides touchesEnded
pauseButton?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
sceneView.overlaySKScene = overlay
```

If the user touches a button, the button's touch events (`touchesBegan`, `touchesEnded` etc) will fire and consume the touch (underlying gesture recognizers *will* still fire though). If they touch outside of a button however, the touch will pass through to the underlying SCNView.

Comment: is there a way to prevent underlying gesture recongnizers to fire on the touch of the overlay button?

Comment: No I don't think so. As gesture recognizers can't be attached to an SKNode,  you'd have to attach them to the SCNView and then query whether they touch any of the SKNodes in the overlay. If not, then query the SCNNodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this method in spritekitHUD:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) 
{
   game.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}
```